# Updated 13.04 to 13.10 to bet VLC 2.1.0 but I'm stuck on 2.0.9

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, vlc

I updated 13.04 to 13.10 only to get VLC 2.1.0 but now when I do this...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

it still won't update to 2.1.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PPA currently only has VLC 2.0.8 for Ubuntu 13.10. See [the PPA's package details
 page](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily/+packages) for what packages are available.

Comment: When I searched google there were numerous sites that had instructions on how to update to 2.1.0 and explicitly stated they were for ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @user1933677 just because some sites said something doesn't mean they were correct ;)

Comment: According to [the build log](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily/+builds?build_state=built) there have been VLC 2.1.0 packages for 13.10 (built on 2013-10-22), but for some reason the PPA owner seems to have removed them. Please contact the PPA owner if you want to know the reasons.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch thanks for the info.  I thought I had taken crazy pills.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try manually installing the [deleted packages](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=saucy), maybe it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

`stable-daily` repo only contains build from maintenance branch aka bug/security fixes. Since 2.1.0 is major release on `< 14.04`, you won't find the build version in the repo.

If bleeding edge build is what you want, you should use the `master-daily` repo (https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/master-daily)

Comment: So is there anyway I can get stable 2.1.2 on 13.04?
I can get nightly with the ppa which is buggy and crushed all the time.